# Difference between requests.request('POST' and request.post

Tags: python

what would it be the difference between these two sentences:

```
res = requests.request('POST', url)
```

and

```
res = requests.request.post(url)
```

Comment: I can't test atm but is `res = requests.request.post(url)` valid? Isn't it just `requests.post(url)`? Is this the standard `requests` module?

Answer (score 13):

They are pretty much the same thing: https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/177dd90f18a8f4dc79a7d2049f0a3f4fcc5932a0/requests/api.py#L103-L115

`requests.post(…)` is just a wrapper around `requests.request('POST', …)`. As long as you're using standards methods, the former helps readability and reduces the risk of easily avoidable mistakes, while writing the verb.

**Edit:** updated the source reference, since the domain docs.python-requests.org has expired, and the previous link (<s>http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/#post</s>) is now invalid.